# CostExplore keeps returning a validation error that doesn't make sense

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cost-explorer

I have the following TypeScript function to try and get Savings Plan Coverage from AWS (documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CostExplorer.html#getSavingsPlansCoverage-property).

```
async function queryCostExplorerDiscountRate(dateRanges: DateRanges, costExplorer: CostExplorer): Promise<any> {
  const params = {
    TimePeriod: {
      Start: '2023-01-08',
      End: '2023-20-08',
    },
    SortBy: {
      Key: "CoveragePercentage"
    }
  };
  
  const response = await costExplorer.getSavingsPlansCoverage(params).promise();

  return 2; //dummy value for now
}
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

```
ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "ValidationException: end date past the beginning of next month",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "ValidationException",
        "errorMessage": "end date past the beginning of next month",
        "code": "ValidationException",
        "message": "end date past the beginning of next month",
        "time": "2023-09-26T07:22:59.156Z",
        "requestId": "b55d7225-0a46-4b9f-a7f2-d73ead7217ff, 8743fc2f-c612-438f-912a-f1681bf9b8ee",
        "statusCode": 400,
        "retryable": false,
        "retryDelay": 20.834883002095907,
        "stack": [
            "ValidationException: end date past the beginning of next month",
            "    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:61:27)",
            "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
            "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
            "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)",
            "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
            "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
            "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)",
            "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: ValidationException: end date past the beginning of next month",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1250:17)",
        "    at process.emit (node:events:513:28)",
        "    at process.emit (node:domain:489:12)",
        "    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:140:20)",
        "    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:274:27)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:97:32)"
    ]
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error because I've set my End date to be in the current month (and not the next). I've tried many variations of the date strings, but still get this error. Help!?!?!?!?